# Docker as .msi installable

Tags: docker

Is it possible to create a distributable docker image, that can be easily installed on Windows machines?

I don't want the customer to have to install anything first. I want it to appear as a normal software installl.

Comment: What windows OS are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

Well it should be possible but it is a heavy task.

First you probably need to have a different installer for each Windows flavor.

For Windows Server 2016 you can execute from the installer powershell commands to enable containers then install the docker client embedded in your installer and then issue the he docker pull and run commands. And so on.

For Windows 10 pro embed the docker for Windows installer and call it silently. Then execute the docker commands

For other windows versions embed the docker toolbox installer and so on

With many test I think it should be achievable.

But I think should be an easier way to do it

Regards